# Postgres-XL happens ERROR:maximum number of prepared transactions reached

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking, postgres-xl

I am testing `Postgres-XL 9.5r1.2`. I build a cluster with `gtm`, `coord1`, `datanode1`, `datanode2`.

I use `pgbench` to test its performance with below commands:

```
pgbench -h db -U postgres -i -s 100 testdb;
pgbench -h db -U postgres -c 70 -t 40 -r testdb
```

In the test result, the below error happens many times

```
Client NN aborted in state 13: ERROR:  maximum number of prepared transactions reached
HINT:  Increase max_prepared_transactions (currently 10).
```

So, it seems that I need to adjust `max_prepared_transactions`.

My problem is, on which host should I adjust `postgresql.conf` ? `coord1` ? `datanode1` and `datanode2` ? or what else ?

Answer (score 3):

You can set `max_prepared_transactions` in `postgres.conf` for both coordinator and datanodes, but it needs to be set differently:

- For datanodes: `max_connections` of datanodes.
- For coordinator: at least the number of coordinators in the cluster.

See [Postgres-XL docs](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/server-start.html).

Note that `max_connections` also needs to be set differently for coordinator and datanodes:

- For datanodes: sum of `max_connections` of all coordinators.
- For coordinator: number of connections accepted from client application.